# Pass jquery event to layer behind OR make inner radius transparent

Tags: jquery, events, hover, flot

I'm trying to make a pie chart on top of another pie chart (see below) and am using the flot jquery library.

http://cadmiumconsulting.com/carlsberg/screenshot_01.jpg

I have managed to get the diagram looking right but would like to use mouse events on the outer pie chart.

My problem is:

If I draw the outer chart first with the inner one 'on top', mouse events only work on the inner layer.

If on the other hand I draw the inner chart first and add the outer chart 'on top' with an inner radius, the inner radius doesn't work in internet explorer 8 and displays a solid circle over the top of the inner chart.

Any ideas on how to pass events from one layer to the other or force the transparency of the inner radius?

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE - There seems to be an issue with 'globalCompositeOperation' which would allow the transparency. It's included in html5 but not in the excanvas object which is a hack to replicate the canvas object in IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with 'globalCompositeOperation' which would allow the transparency. It's included in html5 but not in the excanvas object which is a hack to replicate the canvas object in IE8. Decided to abandon flot for the example I'm building and create the charts myself using canvas operations.

Answer (score 0):

Events traveling so you should be able to target the chart in the background. I have made this 
simple guide that explains how events travel and how to stop them in jQuery:

First we create our test DOM

```
<div><br/>
    <a class="a1">Im plain simple</a><br/><br/>
    <a class="a2" href="http://google.com">I prevent my own other events</a><br/><br/>
    <a class="a3">I stop other event</a><br/><br/>
    <a class="a4" href="http://google.com">Im shitty</a><br/><br/>
    <a class="a5" href="http://google.com">Im shitty too</a><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
div {background:red;}
a {color:white;}
a.a1 {background:yellow;color:black;}
a.a2 {background:green;}
a.a3 {background:blue;}
a.a4 {background:orange;}
```

jQuery:

We bind a click event to the div to test our travelings

```
$("div").bind("click", function(event) {
    alert("div clicked");
});
```

Click event that travels to the div eventually

```
$("a.a1").bind("click", function(event) {
    alert("a.a1 clicked");
});
```

Using `event.preventDefault()` prevents all `$("a.a2")` other bound click events.

```
$("a.a2").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("a.a2 clicked\n\nactually I was supposed to go to http://google.com");
});
```

Using `event.stopPropagation()` prevents the click event from traveling and it never triggers the bounds events on our `div`

```
$("a.a3").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("a.a3 clicked");
});
```

Now we use there to in combination.

```
$("a.a4").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("a.a4 clicked\n\nI was also supposed to go to http://google.com");
});
```

And another way is to return false; in the end this also works for `live` events.

```
$("a.a5").bind("click", function(event) {
    alert("a.a5 clicked\n\nI was also supposed to go to http://google.com");
    return false;
});
```

Hopes this helps.

If you want more help please post some code (where you bind your events) or an example to your charts